# Change all image names except app icon build phase xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, bash, shell

I am working on an ipad project that requires changing the formatting of image names for the project in a run script build phase in xcode 5. I am running the following script:

```
for f in ${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${FULL_PRODUCT_NAME}/*.png
do
fileName=${f:${#BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}+${#FULL_PRODUCT_NAME}+2:${#f}}
lc='echo $fileName | tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]"
lc=`echo $lc | tr - _`
lc=${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${FULL_PRODUCT_NAME}/${lc}
mv $f $lc
done
```

The script finds all images in the bundle and makes the names all lowercase and changes uses of '-' to '_'. This works perfectly for my situation, however it is also changing the name of the app icon and launch images resulting in them not being used by the app.

What I want is either a way to have the script skip the app icon and launch images, or a way to simply change the names of the images in xcode so that the resulting name from the script is the accurate name.

The biggest issue I have had with simply manually changing the names is that I cannot find how xcode is controlling the naming system because the names I have for the images are already in the proper format so xcode must be creating its own names for the icon and launch images.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming standard naming, and that you don't also have your own files that begin with "Icon" or "Default", you could do this.  If you have your own images that match that pattern, you will need to add special cases below, or specifically target all the various icon and launch image files.

```
for f in ${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${FULL_PRODUCT_NAME}/*.png
do
    BASENAME=$(basename $f)
    if [[ ${BASENAME} == Icon* ]] || [[ ${BASENAME} == Default* ]] ;
    then
        echo "App icon or launch image, leaving file alone"
    else
        fileName=${f:${#BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}+${#FULL_PRODUCT_NAME}+2:${#f}}
        lc=`echo $fileName | tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]"`
        lc=`echo $lc | tr - _`
        lc=${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${FULL_PRODUCT_NAME}/${lc}
        mv "$f" "$lc"
    fi
done
```

Comment: that looks like it might work, I will try it tomorrow thanks.

Comment: the script worked like it should. However for some reason xcode still has issues with the app icon and launch images. So I am not sure what is going on, but the script does answer the question at least.

Comment: So your app is not getting an icon at all?

Comment: no, if I take out the entire script then the icon and launch screen get added, but for some reason having the script in there makes the icon and launch screen not show up

Comment: Change the line `mv "$f" "$lc"` to `echo "mv $f $lc` and see what all the files are.  There must be some other file that it is renaming that is used for the icon and launch images.  If you look in your Info.plist, do you have settings for the app icons?  Newer apps do not put that in the Info.plist, but you used to be able to identify your icon files there, and it wouldn't rely on the naming.  But I think in the .app directory, it would change them to the standard names.